# Deploy Rails App with capistrano : Foundation : Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable : "$oil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to deploy a Rails app with capistrano
I use foundation-rails, and when I deploy, i've got this error :

> Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$oil".

Even if I had manually $oil in my sass file, it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by downgrading foundation-rails gem !

Thanks for your help